# How to store a thread on a Web Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.7.2

I'm working on a legacy code made in .Net Framework 4.7, very old, I don't know too much about it as I started programming on .Net Core onwards. There is a mix of vb.net and c#, classes with 40k lines of code (90% of the code was program as structured programming, even seeing the same piece of code repeated below) and methods with 3.5k lines of code, so big refactoring's is a no no, it is already in prod.

**Problem:**
Someone created a `Thread` to finish a method and don't block the GUI when clicking a button, is a new(ed) up instance of `Thread` in the middle of a class. This `Thread` needs to finish before reaching a certain point in the GUI, the idea is to check if the thread finished when someone clicks a button, the other button is on another page and it postback.

**Question:**
How can I add a reference to an `IEnumerable` of these particular managed threads and ask if the last one finished?

**What I tried:**
Because I have never used Threads and never 'newed' up something this important in the middle of a 40k lines of code class, the only thing I tried that they are doing is to try and store some sort of flag on `Session`, problem is, how do you update the flag?.

Comment: Could you share a little code snippet to better explicit your problem ?

Comment: Sure!, let me add it as an edit on the question.